# Multiple Chained Dependencies, Some of Which Require Run Time Arguments

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am setting up dependency injection for a Web Service project with Castle Windsor. I have some classes that depend on runtime arguments that are also dependencies for other classes. I have a somewhat working solution for this problem, but it gets messy as the dependency chain gets longer with runtime arguments. I am trying to implement a more elegant solution.

I have some of these dependencies resolved with a TypedFactoryFacility that I am registering like this:

```
public interface ISomeClassFactory
{
   ISomeClass Create(ISomeSimpleDependency dependency);
}

...

public interface ISomeSimpleDependencyFactory
{
   ISomeSimpleDependency Create(string runtimeArgument);
}

...

public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Register(
        Component.For<ISomeClass>().ImplementedBy<SomeClass>(),
        Component.For<ISomeClassFactory().AsFactory());
    container.Register(
        Component.For<ISomeSimpleDepencency>().ImplementedBy<SomeSimpleDependency>(),
        Component.For<ISomeSimpleDepencencyFactory().AsFactory());
}
```

And called like this:

```
public void WebServiceMethod(string runtimeArgument)
{
    ISomeSimpleDependency someSimpleDependency = container.Resolve<ISomeSimpleDependencyFactory>().Create(runtimeArgument);
    ISomeClass someClass = container.Resolve<ISomeSimpleClassFactory>().Create(someSimpleDependency);
    // the rest of the method
}
```

Thgis works, but there are some problems with this. Even if I do not need to call any methods on someSimpleDependency, I have to instantiate it to have it as a dependency for someClass  (this is the original problem that I was tring to solve by implementing dependency injection in this project). Furthermore, things get more tricky when I have a class that has a runtime dependency that is several layers down in the dependency chain:

```
ISomeClass -> IDependency1 -> IDependency2 -> IDependency3 -> runtimeArgument
```

Is there any way to instantiate someClass with out having factory methods chaining up from dependency 3?

```
public void WebServiceMethod(string runtimeArgument)
{
    IDependency3 dependency3= container.Resolve<IDependency3Factory>().Create(runtimeArgument);
    IDependency2 dependency2 = container.Resolve<IDependency2Factory>().Create(dependency3);
    IDependency1 dependency1 = container.Resolve<IDependency1Factory>().Create(dependency2);

    ISomeClass someClass = container.Resolve<ISomeClassFactory>().Create(dependency1);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best solution to this problem, but I was able to get a working solution using [Scoped Lifestyle](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md).

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Register(Component.For<ISomeClass>().ImplementedBy<SomeClass>());
    container.Register(Component.For<IDependency1>().ImplementedBy<Dependency1>());
    container.Register(
        Component.For<ISomeSimpleDepencency>().ImplementedBy<ISomeSimpleDepencency>().LifeStyleScoped(),
        Component.For<ISomeSimpleDepencencyFactory().AsFactory());
}
```

And in the invoking method

```
public void WebServiceMethod(string runtimeArgument)
{
    using (container.BeginScope())
    {
        IDependency3 dependency3= container.Resolve<ISomeSimpleDepencencyFactory>().Create(runtimeArgument);

        ISomeClass someClass = container.Resolve<ISomeClass>());
    }
}
```

The instance using the run time parameter will be retained in the scope.
I'm not marking this as the answer because I'm not yet convinced that there isn't a better solution